# Extract img src from a text element in an XML feed

Tags: php, xml, domdocument, domxpath

I have an XML feed that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<smf:xml-feed xmlns:smf="http://www.simplemachines.org/" xmlns="http://www.simplemachines.org/xml/recent" xml:lang="en-US">
  <recent-post>
    <time>April 04, 2021, 04:20:47 pm</time>
    <id>1909114</id>
    <subject>Title</subject>
    <body><![CDATA[<a href="#"><img src="image.png">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Iure rerum in tempore sit ducimus doloribus quod commodi eligendi ipsam porro non fugiat nisi eaque delectus harum aspernatur recusandae incidunt quasi.</a>]]></body>
  </recent-post>
</smf:xml-feed>
```

I want to extract the image `src` from the `body` and then save it to a new XML file that includes an element for `image`.

So far, I have

```
$xml = 'https://example.com/feed.xml';
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$dom->formatOutput = true;
$dom->recover = true;
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadXML($xml);

$xpath = new DOMXPath( $dom );
$nodes = $xpath->query( 'smf:xml-feed/recent-post/body' );

foreach( $nodes as $node )
{
    $html = new DOMDocument();
    $html->loadHTML( $node->nodeValue );
    $src = $html->getElementsByTagName( 'img' )->item(0)->getAttribute('src');
    echo $src;
}
```

But when I try to print out `$nodes`, I get nothing. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a Simple Machines feed. However the namespaces are missing and the "body" element should be a CDATA section with an html fragment as text. I would expect to look like this:

```
<smf:xml-feed 
  xmlns:smf="http://www.simplemachines.org/" 
  xmlns="http://www.simplemachines.org/xml/recent" 
  xml:lang="en-US">
    <recent-post>
    <time>April 04, 2021, 04:20:47 pm</time>
    <id>1909114</id>
    <subject>Title</subject>
    <body><![CDATA[
    <a href="#"><img src="image.png">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Iure rerum in tempore sit ducimus doloribus quod commodi eligendi ipsam porro non fugiat nisi eaque delectus harum aspernatur recusandae incidunt quasi.</a>
    ]]>
    </body>
  </recent-post>
</smf:xml-feed>
```

The XML defines two namespaces. To use them in Xpath expressions you have to register prefixes for them. I suggest iterating the `recent-post` elements. Then fetch the text content of specific child nodes using expression with string casts.

The `body` element contains the HTML fragment as text, so you need to load it into a separate document. Then you can Xpath on this document to fetch the `src` of the `img`:

```
$feedDocument = new DOMDocument();
$feedDocument->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$feedDocument->loadXML($xmlString);
$feedXpath = new DOMXPath($feedDocument);

// register namespaces
$feedXpath->registerNamespace('smf', 'http://www.simplemachines.org/');
$feedXpath->registerNamespace('recent', 'http://www.simplemachines.org/xml/recent');

// iterate the posts
foreach($feedXpath->evaluate('/smf:xml-feed/recent:recent-post') as $post) {
    // demo: fetch post subject as string
    var_dump($feedXpath->evaluate('string(recent:subject)', $post));
    
    // create a document for the HTML fragment
    $html = new DOMDocument();
    $html->loadHTML(
        // load the text content of the body element
        $feedXpath->evaluate('string(recent:body)', $post),
        // just a fragment, no need for html document elements or DTD
        LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD
    );
    // Xpath instance for the html document
    $htmlXpath = new DOMXpath($html);
    // fetch first src attribute of an img 
    $src = $htmlXpath->evaluate('string(//img/@src)');
    var_dump($src);
}
```

Output:

```
string(5) "Title"
string(9) "image.png"
```

Comment: Sorry, I viewed the feed in a browser tab and originally copied the code from there but it didn't include any of the namespace or CDATA information. After viewing the source of the page I was able to see that and I've updated the code in my post.

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems with your code, some which I have to make assumptions on...

In

```
$dom->loadXML($xml);
```

this is expecting the actual source XML and not a URL, you would need to use `load()` instead.

I would have to assume that the `smf` namespace is defined somewhere in the document, for testing purposes I have altered the sample XML to...

```
<smf:xml-feed xml:lang="en-US" xmlns:smf="http://a.com">
```

I've also altered the query to

```
//smf:xml-feed/recent-post/body
```

to test this code.

Finally, not sure why you create another document inside the loop, but you should be able to process this directly from the node in the loop, so I use `$node` as the base for the `getElementsByTagName()` call...

```
$xml = 'https://example.com/feed.xml';
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$dom->formatOutput = true;
$dom->recover = true;
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->load($xml);

$xpath = new DOMXPath( $dom );
$nodes = $xpath->query( '//smf:xml-feed/recent-post/body' );

foreach( $nodes as $node )
{
    $src = $node->getElementsByTagName( 'img' )->item(0)->getAttribute('src');
    echo $src;
}
```

Comment: Also - the `img` tag within the snippet of HTML also needs attention - as a self-closing element it needs the `/` to close the element otherwise it is causing errors for the parser.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake when I originally posted the feed code. See my comment to ThW above.